# problems with quotes in SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, quotes, netezza

Inside a procedure I have a variable that contains SQL for example like this:

```
examplesql:= 'SELECT 'asd';';
```

Where the SQL itself is enclosed with single '' and a value further inside the SQL is also enclosed with single ''.  I tried using double "" marks instead but it didnt work. Any suggestions how to accomplish this in Netezza ? 
The variable examplesql is later called with EXECUTE IMMIDIATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the same as (almost) every other DBMS, you need to double the single quotes within the string:

```
examplesql:= 'SELECT ''O''''Hara';
```

Comment: You need one extra set of single quotes in/around the literal there for inside the SPROC body. It should be examplesql:= 'SELECT ''O''''Hara'' ';